# cakephp: how to access another model, which has no association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've 3 tables:
`project`, `amenities` and `project_amenities`.

I add project form only, i want to add new amenities, which first added to amenities table and then project_amenities table.

So I defined these relations:

`Project hasMany Amenities`

`Amenity belongsTo Project`

I declared in `projects_controller`:
`var $uses = array('Amenity');`

This gives error for my add action here

```
if (!empty($this->data)){

    $this->Project->create();
```

as

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: ProjectsController::$Project 
[APP\controllers\projects_controller.php, line 60]
```

**edit**
Also, I cannot do:

```
$this->Amenity->create();
$insertData = array('name' => $this->data['Project']['Amenity'][$i]['name']);
$this->Amenity->save($insertData);
```

Comment: also, I cant do this,
$this->Amenity->create(); 
$insertData = array('name' => $this->data['Project']['Amenity'][$i]['name']);
     $this->Amenity->save($insertData);

Comment: Judging by your tables' names, you might want to change your `Project<->Amenity` association to [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM), renaming `project_amenities` to `projects_amenities`.

Comment: yes renamed project_amenities to projects_amenities...also changed relation in Amenities as hasMany Projects..still insert in this table is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to use `$this->loadModel('ModelName');` in the function where you needed. Then you can use the model as below

```
$this->ModelName->function();
```

By using `$uses` array it make available to entire controller. Which will affect your performance.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't recommend using $uses = array() as it defies the purpose of having model relationships. Plus it adds a fair bit of overhead too.

You should use your model relationships where ever possible:

```
$this->Project->create();
$this->Project->Amenity->create();
$this->Model1->Model2->Model3->Model4->create();
```

If you want to use an unrelated model, you can do:

```
$this->loadModel('NewModelName');
$this->NewModelName->action();
```

Check out http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data and http://book.cakephp.org/view/992/loadModel

Answer (score 0):

you must specify the project model in your $uses variable:

```
$uses = array('Project','Amenity');
```

but I'm curious why do you have three tables when you need one to many relationship?

Comment: seems to me that its a NxN relationship because of the intermediary table `project_amenities`

Comment: yeap but OP doesn't use the third table... as he described, it's one-to-many relation

Comment: This is the reason for your error, but you should not need to, as Cake makes these associations automatically based on the keys within your tables. Do you have `project_id` in your amenity table?

Comment: Only clarifying what I think was already said: you DO NOT need the $uses variable.

Comment: Dont i need $uses,if i"ve many to many relationship for project_amenities table? I've changed relation in Amenities as hasMany Projects. Then how can I add entries in this table...

Comment: If I remove $uses, then it gives error for Amenity. Also
Why this is not working
for($i = 0; $i< count($this->data['Project']['Amenity']);$i++){
$this->Amenity->create(); 
     $insertData = array('name' => $this->data['Project']['Amenity'][$i]['name']);
     $amenity = $this->Amenity->save($insertData);
$data['AmenityArr']  = array(
          'project_id' =>  $this->Project->getLastInsertID(),
          'amenity_id' => $this->Amenity->getLastInsertID()
     );
$this->Project->Amenity->save($data['AmenityArr']);

Answer (score 0):

Solution for :save for hasAndBelongsToMany

I created 
model: projects_amenity.php which has relation belongsTo project and amenity.
model: projects has relation hasAndBelongsToMany with amenity
controller: projects_amenities_controller

and in code:

```
$this->loadModel('ProjectsAmenity');
for($i = 0; $i< count($this->data['Project']['Amenity']);$i++)
{                       
    $this->Amenity->create();   

    $insertData = array('name' => $this->data['Project']['Amenity'][$i]['name']);
    $amenity = $this->Amenity->save($insertData);   

    $amenityid = $this->Amenity->getLastInsertID();

    $projectid = $this->Project->getLastInsertID();

    $this->ProjectsAmenity->create();           
    $data['AmenityArr']  = array('project_id' =>  $projectid,'amenity_id' => $amenityid );

    $this->ProjectsAmenity->save($data['AmenityArr']);  
}
```